# Python match string in path and replace with previous path items

Tags: python, regex, uri

Suppose that I have this path (string type)

```
/user/{id}/list/{id}
```

I want to search for 'id' and for each **exact** match, I want to replace the id with the immediate previous path + '_id'. So in the above a example the described process will result to

```
/user/{user_id}/list/{list_id}
```

How can I do this in python?

Edit: I also want to store the new id names in variables, so I guess the operation should not be in place.

Edit2: There can be an indefinite number of {id} occurrences in the path

Comment: can you show the real example?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  What do you mean, this is actually an exact example of my situation

Comment: *to store the new id names in variables* - would be there only 2 *id names* (as in your url) or their number would be dynamic?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Their number is dynamic

Comment: show how should look the final data structure storing *the new id names*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It can be either temporal storing (so inside a temporal variable in a loop step) or it can be stored in any collection variable like list, dict or tuple in any format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a capture group and a reference to this capture in the replacement string:

```
re.sub(r'([^/]+)/{id}', r'\1/{\1_id}', s)
```

if you want to store the replacements for example in a list, you can do that:

*(python 2.7)*

```
def rep(m):
    ids.append('%s_id'%m.group(1))
    return '%(g1)s/{%(g1)s_id}'%{'g1':m.group(1)}

ids=[]

re.sub(r'([^/]+)/{id}', rep, s)
```

*(python 3.x)*

```
def rep(m):
    ids.append('{}_id'.format(m.group(1)))
    return '{0}/{{{0}_id}}'.format(m.group(1))
```